# Pandas DataFrame : ValueError: Length of values (13) does not match length of index (12)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I was trying to run the below code from `Pycharm` and from `Jupyter Notebook`. In Jupyter the error didn't occur while Pycharm did. Can Someone help to figure out the issue?

*Below is the dataset visualization of news_collection.csv*

> created_at,text
> 5/13/2021 3:27:55 PM,"Srilanka team is well prepared for the worldCup 2021"
> 5/13/2021 3:27:55 PM,"They will be missing Lasith Malinga for sure"

*Below is the code that gives the above error*

```
import pandas as pd

def aggregated():
    tweets = pd.read_csv(r'news_collection.csv')
    df = pd.DataFrame(tweets, columns=['created_at', 'text'])
    df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
    df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
    pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 0)
    df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='created_at', freq='1D')).agg(lambda x: ' 
    '.join(set(x)))
    return df


   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(aggregated())
    aggregated().to_csv(r'preprocessed_tweets_aggregated.csv',index = True, 
    header=True)
```

Comment: Both have the same `pd.__version__`?

Comment: @LemonPy yes versions are the same. And what makes it throws this particular error?

Comment: Could be that you are not running on the same `news_collection.csv` file?

Comment: no it's the same file

Comment: On which line exactly are you getting the error?

Comment: df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='created_at', freq='1D')).agg(lambda x: ' '.join(set(x)))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237353/discussion-between-niroshan-ratnayake-and-lemonpy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue which had thrown the error is due to a **version issue in the pandas package in Pycharm**. I was running the same code on Jupyter with pandas 1.1.5 version while in Pycharm running with pandas 1.3.0 which wasn't working. 
***So to change a package version in Pycharm you can follow the below steps***(In my case I had to downgrade the pandas version to 1.1.5)

> Step 01 - Goto your project in Pycharm and Select the options as below

[image]

> Step 02 - Then You will direct to "Python Interpreter" tab -> Select the Package You want to Change(Pandas in my case) -> Double click on the Version -> Select the Specify Version check box -> Give the version you want to upgrade or downgrade -> Select Install Package

[image]